# Need help in designing classes for implementing tcp telegram code

Tags: c#, tcp, protocols

I want to implement a "framework", written in C#, to use with a windows forms application.

This framework is intended to implement some basic methods that allow to send and receive byte arrays over TCP/IP sockets, and convert these byte arrays from and to specific classes that implement different TCP/IP telegrams which consist of header data and payload data.

I thought of using interfaces, some abstract base classes and based upon them the distinct implementation for different protocols.

I already designed the interface, but with the limitation that I cannot have static members or constructors declarad in that interface.

This is my interface:

```
public interface ITcpTelegramm<T> where T : struct
```

Based upon this, i declared

```
using IUInt16TcpTelegramm  = ITcpTelegramm<UInt16>;
public abstract class TcpTelegramm : IUInt16TcpTelegramm
```

In which I implemented the interface as abstract methods

```
public abstract IUInt16TcpTelegramm Analyse(byte[] daten);
```

So every class that inherits *TcpTelegramm* must declare implementations of those methods.

But because interfaces cannot contain static methods and static methods cannot be abstract i cannot force inherited classes to implement *Analyse* as static:

```
public static IUInt16TcpTelegramm Analyse(byte[] daten)
{
    /* some code that analyses the byte array and creates an object
       that represents the TCP/IP telegram object in the array */
}
```

So right now I am stuck a little.
Either I give up using static methods or using abstract base classes.

Comment: Are you talking about the telegram messenger? https://core.telegram.org/api

Comment: Why does `Analyse()` have to be static? And what is your _question_? You already know interfaces can't include static members, so surely you're not asking how to do that. So what _are_ you asking? And what problem do you have that is specific enough to avoid being open to many different possible answers?

Comment: The `Analyse()` method implements the factory pattern. So I decided, it has to be static. :-)

And no, it is not the telegram messenger. It shall be a test application for my application that uses different proprietary TCP/IP communication protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you can't declare `static` methods as `abstract` and it is probably also not a good idea to just make the method non-`static` to work around this problem, as it creates bad design.

I would actually go for a slightly different route. Your `static` method is an implementation of the factory method pattern. As far as I can see, all your class will have such a method. Why not create a factory class that implements an interface containing all the factory methods you need?

In my eyes this solution would be superior, because

- It separates the creation logic of your classes from their implementation
- You can reuse creation logic more easily (which is likely to be the case, as your objects are closely related it seems)

You can read more about the factory patterns [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Comment: The factory pattern wasnt directly in my mind, but it seems to be a good approach on my problem. So I should create an `ITCPTelegramFactory`and from this I implement my base class and inherited classes.